\ifnum to draw a tikzpicture, less than or equals
I want to make a conditional statement that draws one tikz picture for specific values of \t and another for different \t values.
Here is a M(non)WE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\def \t {3}
\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\t>=2}{
\tikz\draw[red](0,0)--(1,1);}
{\tikz\draw[blue](0,1)--(1,0);}
\end{document}

Furthermore, I'd like to use "less than or equals" instead of just "less than," which doesn't seem to be supported, according to an error message I received. Is there a way to accomplish this? (i.e. <= instead of just <)

Off-topic: Using \def is not recommended in LaTeX. You should always use \newcommand to avoid accidental overwriting of commands. Especially the one-letter commands also internally used by LaTeX are endangered. \t is one of them.

Similar question: loops - Less than or equal comparison within a whiledo - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange

\t>=2 is the opposite of \t<2, so you can use \not{\t<2}:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\newcommand\Vt{3}% avoid accidental redefinition of \t
\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\not{\Vt<2}}{%
\tikz\draw[red](0,0)--(1,1);}
{\tikz\draw[blue](0,1)--(1,0);}
\end{document}

or just swap the then and else part:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\newcommand\Vt{3}% avoid accidental redefinition of \t
\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\Vt<2}{\tikz\draw[blue](0,1)--(1,0);}
{\tikz\draw[red](0,0)--(1,1);}
\end{document}

As an alternative you can use TikZ math library, which allows condition >=:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\newcommand\Vt{3}% avoid accidental redefinition of \t
\begin{document}
\tikz\tikzmath{
  if \Vt >= 2 then {{\draw[red](0,0)--(1,1);};}
  else {{\draw[blue](0,1)--(1,0);};};
};
\end{document}


It's working on my local installation, but when I try to run it with a python script, I'm getting this error message, do you know what I might be able to do to fix it?(C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/translator\translator-t
heorem-dictionary-English.dict) (file_1.nav)
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.

@Tyler Which one? And sorry, but I don't know your python script and how it runs LaTeX. If it writes a TeX file, before running LaTeX, have a look into that file. If you run the python script on another computer, test if the installation on that computer is up-to-date. Sorry, but there it not enough information to tell you, why your python script fails. If needed, ask a follow-up question.

110 updates! Thanks for the advice. By the way, I was able to circumvent the problem by doing an if then in python and create a different tex file for each condition.

Wen you are using LuaTeX, then you can define \ifthenelse by Lua code:
\def\ld#1{\luaescapestring{\detokenize{#1}}}
\def\ifthenelse#1#2#3{\directlua{if #1 then tex.print("\ld{#2}") 
                                       else tex.print("\ld{#3}") end}}

\def\t{3}

\ifthenelse{\t>=2}{ YES } { NO }

\bye


This is rather flaky since it will fully expand any control sequence in #2 and #3 as well as interpreting any remaining \ as an escape character for "…".

Yes, I know about it. My code was only a draft idea. If we want to put control sequences to #2 and #3 then we must to combine \detokenize with \luaescapestring. I added this to my code.
